# Unable to open/download pdf files after committing in to svn repository

Tags: svn, pdf, fedora

i am very newbie in using `svn repository`  for version maintenance,

I have installed svn sucessfully on my machine(fedora 15)

suppose i had given below link to access files

```
http://example.com/svn-repos/folder/
```

I had applied following commands to add  the folders `Documentation` and  `Anotherfolder`
Actually the folder `Documentation` consists of `pdf` files and `docx` files.

```
svn add Documentation
svn commit -m "Creating Folder" Documentation

svn add Anotherfolder
svn commit -m "Creating Folder" Anotherfolder
```

The structure is as given below

```
svn-repos - Revision 2: /folder

Documentation/
       Material/
               Prsentfinance.docx
               Transferfile.pdf
               kelvinref.pdf
               solutionsparts.pdf
Anotherfolder/
```

Here actually the folders with files has been sucessfully added to svn repository, but when i tried to open `pdf` files under `Material` folder they are unable to open and displays nothing, and when i clicked on `Prsentfinance.docx` it has been downloaded.

Can anyone let me know why unable to open/download pdf files when we click on them, whether pdf files doesn't work on svn repository or we need to do any further process for uploading pdf files in to svn repository.

Comment: Just to clarify: The pdfs display o.k. before committing them to subversion, but are broken after commit?

Comment: @Martin:Actually before commit when i opened pdf's they are working fine,but i don't know they are broken after committing to subversions or not , when i clicked on the pdf after committing, the browser just refreshing and not downloading or opening the pdf but the same working fine in firefox

Comment: Seems to be a problem of "the browser".

Comment: is it a chrome problem , if so how can we solve that, upgrading ?

Comment: I've flagged this question for closing: It is entirely unclear _what_ you are doing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try setting...

```
svn propset svn:executable 'ON' -R path/file.pdf
```

Comment: Sorry if am wrong, what the above command will do and path/to/pdf in the sense i am committing entire folder but not individual pdf file, and whether i need to give local machine path of pdf or else  directly server like                             svn propset svn:executable 'ON' -R Documentation/Material/Transferfile.pdf

Comment: Provide path to all PDF files.

Comment: k i got it, but my question is which path?, the path of pdf on our local system or else path of pdf on svn server

Comment: On your local system go the the path and execute the following... `svn propset svn:executable 'ON' -R *.pdf` and then do a `svn commit`

Comment: Thanks for u r continuos support, k i had done the same and got property 'svn:executable' set on 'Transferfile.pdf' and after that i had went to the link http://example.com/svn-repos/folder/  in browser and clicked that pdf file and same continues no result

Comment: Can you repeat the process with a fresh check-in and see?

Comment: Thanks, actually its working in mozilla firefox but not working in google chrome

Comment: Why should it help to set the _executable_ property?

Answer (score -1):

Did you treat it as a binary file object? It is not a text file (and altering a single byte will corrupt it).

Comment: No I din't committed the pdf files individually, but i had committed the entire folder "Material" which consists of pdf files and docx files.Here docx file is opening but pdf files are not opening

Comment: You are confusing SVN with CVS. SVN has no problem with (untagged) binary files: http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#binary-files This will only affect rendering of e.g. diffs.